# User upload file above web root with php

Tags: php, file-upload, streaming

I have a website where local bands can have a profile page, I'm implementing an upload system so that they can add songs to their profile.

I want to make sure that clever visitors to my website cannot download their songs.

I was thinking about uploading them to above the folder for my domain so that they cannot be accessed directly. Is this a good idea and/or possible? If not, what do you suggest I do to try and avoid users downloading songs. I'm already using a flash player to try and prevent downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't stop the very clever as any uri can be intercepted by the user before it's sent and then used as he sees fit. Other users will simply resort to using software to record the song as it plays in their system.

Typical blockades to thwart the less clever (by making uri collection very difficult) are one-time use uri's and streaming servers.

Comment: You can also intercept the Flash web request and download that file directly (a method I use with Pandora).

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic url's for songs.
I mean, instead of reaching the song as /mp3s/someband.mp3, you can generate a dynamic script such as

```
findmp3.php?param=dfsdfdsfedfew87rfy2348rf48fg834
```

where param will be some hashed data which includes the real path to the file and the haching key is differeent for each request

so even i find that urla and copy and paste it to some download client, it wont work because the key you used for the first time is already used and you wont allow it at the second time.

For encoding the param, you can use [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)

Comment: Even assuming the param is not visible in the HTML, suppose the user configures a proxy or something similar to divert requests for findmp3.php?param=anything from the SWF file so that the "first time" doesn't happen, and then makes the request him/herself?

This is perhaps a bit paranoid, but the only way of being 100% sure is either by embedding the actual data in the SWF, or encrypting the *contents* of the file rather than the request string.

Comment: no way, because the key that generates the crypted parameter will be stored in session (or db), there is no way the client knows it, and the script will get that key from server (session or db) to decrypt the parameter